# HTML5 Webpack Dynamic Drag & Drop

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webrtc, html5-video

**Requirement**

We are having a webrtc call solution where multiple people on a webinar call. we have used a third party WebRTC provider (Agora) with HTML webpack Build code they have shared.
We want to drag , drop and switch the users who are joining the channel . Its a complete HTML5 WebPack code.

**CODE**

Git Code : https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Video-Call/tree/master/One-to-One-Video/Agora-Web-Tutorial-1to1-Webpack
Front End :  https://webdemo.agora.io/agora-web-showcase/examples/Agora-Web-Tutorial-1to1-Web/

**Problem**
We used JQUERY Draggable and Droppable in the code which we have. But whenever a NEW user is added to the WEBRTC call a new DIV is generated and that is not DRAGABLE or DROPPABLE.

**HELP REQUIRED**
I would appreciate any good drag and drop library which can be used in dynamic users for HTML5 WEBPACK

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you shared Agora code rather than your own code which contains the drag/drop logic. Can you share your code with your drag/drop implementation? It would make it easier to provide a relevant answer as to what might be going wrong.

Regarding drag and drop libraries, I really don't think a library is likely to help you until you know what's going wrong with your current implementation, but here are some options:

- [Draggable](https://github.com/Shopify/draggable) - Originally written by Shopify but now with other maintainers
- [InteractJS](https://github.com/taye/interact.js) - Looks interesting but have not tried this one myself
- (Not a library) Native [HTML drag and drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) - What I've used when implementing similar features in the past, though with Daily rather than Agora (not that this should make a difference for the drag/drop features)